# "C compiler cannot create executables" Error while configuring gcc

Tags: linux, gcc, cross-compiling

I'm on manjaro linux attempting to set up a crosscompiler using [this tutorial](https://wiki.osdev.org/GCC_Cross-Compiler) and I have binutils set up, but when I go to do `../gcc-10.2.0/configure (etc.)` I get this:

```
checking host system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking target system type... i686-pc-elf
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether ln works... yes
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /usr/bin/sed
checking for gawk... gawk
checking for libatomic support... no
checking for libitm support... no
checking for libsanitizer support... no
checking for libvtv support... no
checking for libhsail-rt support... no
checking for libphobos support... no
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/home/morticia/src/build-gcc':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

[config.log](https://pastebin.com/FL23VZbU)

Seeming Error: `Fatal error: no compiled in support for x86_64`

Comment: "Fatal error: no compiled in support for x86_64". Maybe your compiler is 32bit?

Comment: `gcc -dumpmachine` should show you the target arch of the compiler

Comment: this could help you: https://forum.osdev.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&p=220690

Comment: @Kazz thank you I was just looking for a question like that

Comment: @thatotherguy the output of gcc -dumpmachine was: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu

Comment: @Bam How about `as -version`? Does it agree?

Comment: @thatotherguy version 2.36.1, "this assembler was configured for a target of 'i686-elf'"

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that due to the tutorial I was following the assembler was attempting to assemble for i686 while the compiler was attempting to compile for x86_64, I just had to remove the binutils meant for the cross compiler from my path before running ./configure